# Движок не предлагает автора ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, комментарии

Писал [вот тут](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6797/178988) комментарий, но движок почему-то не предложил @VladD в списке вариантов.

I was writing a comment [here](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6797/178988), but for some reason there was no @VladD in candidates list.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Наверное он предполагает, что комментарии как раз относятся к автору (в любом случае он получит уведомление)

Comment: @Nofate, ээээ! Не задумано так. должно быть можно обратиться к автору, если есть хотя бы один другой комментатор, а он там есть. Или давай с подтверждающей ссылкой.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: *Note that the author of the post will always be notified of any new comment. You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.*

Comment: @avp, уведомление без обращения в этом случае получат оба - комментатор и автор. Уведомление с обращением - тот, кому оно адресовано и автор. Если бы комментария не было, движок бы вырезал обращение к автору как ненужное.

Comment: @Nofate, должно же вот так быть? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX8yD.png Хотя, тут автор участвовал в комментировании, а не только как автор сообщения.

Comment: Да, похоже именно в этом отличие: Если автор не комментировал, то его не автокомплитят.

Comment: Получается, что нельзя уведомить только лишь автора поста при таком раскладе, а это не очень хорошо.

Comment: @alexolut, вроде же можно, но только если руками написать?

Comment: @Qwertiy А, ну может быть и так. Хотя, кажется, где-то были ограничения на такой ввод. В приложения что ли.

Comment: @alexolut, там выше есть ссылка от Nofate